# Does a CodeDom Visual Basic .NET parser exist?

Tags: .net, codedom

Does somebody know if someone has created a Visual basic parser to CodeDom (ie, it takes VB.NET as input and create a CodeCompileUnit graph) ?

***SOLUTION***

I've retrieved the source code of [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/), and used their parser, it works just fine !

Comment: Heys could you send me the source code too? The link isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [the CodeDom namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) from the .NET framework?

Answer (score 0):

No - The CodeDomProvider.Parse needs to be inherited\Overriden.

[CodeDomProvider.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.parse?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#exceptions)